# What are some alternatives to Parse?

Tags: mobile, parse-platform, cross-platform

My team and I would like to develop a project that incorporates an Android, iOS and web app. Scalability and big throughput potential is a key feature. We have started to work with Parse.com, and it provides exactly what we're looking for - except for the prohibitive expensiveness of scaling and the absurd limits on queries and requests/second. What are some alternatives to Parse in this sense? We most likely do not need any complex database actions and limited cloud processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As of 02/28/2016 Parse is shutting down.

Comment: It's shocking isn't it. If you can't trust a Facebook owned company to last, who can you trust? Firebase looks like a good alternative but how long will the Google owned company last? Firebase doesn't seem to have the same Push Notification capabilities.

Comment: @elprl StackMob got bought by PayPal and shut down. Then FB buys Parse and shuts it down. I wouldn't be so clear as to use Firebase. Time to switch to AWS as they won't shut down.

Comment: @chris, I totally agree, AWS was the only choice for us. I've been going through the painstaking migration processes for a couple of weeks already. Converting the Parse tables to DynamoDB & CloudCode to Lambda is a real challenge. Thank goodness for AWS Free Tiers.

Comment: @elprl yeah I hear you.  I have the same issue migrating everything. It's a slow and painful process but once it's done should be good for the long haul.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's time us Parse users go to the big boy of cloud services: https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/

Comment: Haha agreed @chris, feel free to message me whenever

Answer (score 0):

Parse is an outstanding option for getting up and running quickly. Don't underestimate the value in being able to rapidly bring an idea to market.

Long term, potential competitors to Parse (e.g. Firebase, PubNub) will not provide meaningful savings when operating at scale. If you are concerned about that you will want to look into developing your own backend services and running them on infrastructure like AWS (Amazon Web Services). At a high level, Parse uses MongoDB for its core database and is entirely hosted using AWS. AWS offers tons of services for managing data, performing computations, load balancing, and so on. They also offer [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) which allows you to access AWS resources and automatically creates client SDKs for you.

As a general rule of thumb, it's much better to focus on building the best possible user experience than to focus too much on scalability. By and large, issues of scalability rarely come into play because most apps fail. Not saying that to be discouraging — just something to keep in mind and prevent you from falling into the trap of over-engineering at the cost of time :)