# searching for a good parse.com alternative

Tags: parse-platform, codenameone, parse4cn1

Its true this question has been asked before but I didn't really get it
My question is: is their an alterative to parse.com that is compatible with codename one? I have seen some like the "back4app", but they all don't seem to work.
My question is:
Are there any good alternatives to parse.com, and how do it get it to work in my cn1 app.

Comment: There is a non-free solution inside CN1. Assuming you are looking for a notification solution, codename one offer a solution.

Comment: We deprecated support for the cloud storage a while back so that's not an option anymore. I'm curious myself, I know some developers use firebase with Codename One but I have deep trust issues with Google in terms of product long term maintenance.

Comment: Added the parse4cn1 tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some alternatives to Parse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685893/what-are-some-alternatives-to-parse)

Answer (score 1):

There are several lists online of alternatives to parse.com, e.g.,

- https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/126098/top-5-parse-alternatives

The main question is: What do YOU want/need? If you want to stay as close to Parse as possible, you should consider Parse Open Source - either setting up your own server or using one of the services like back4apps that help you with that. When you say "they all don't seem to work" what exactly do you mean?

I personally have tried back4apps and it looks promising and the support team is very responsive. Of course, there are no guarantees that it will not shut down someday... However, since they're using the Parse Server, one can argue that you can always migrate away if they vanish. I also successfully set up Parse Server on openshift.com thanks to this excellent [guide](http://www.anttdev.com/2016/02/how-to-install-your-own-parse-server-on-openshift/). Note that, in both cases, I only made test apps for [parse4cn1](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1) so I cannot say anything about production situations (yet).

On the parse4cn1 side, I'm in the process of releasing an update that will allow users specify the backend URL effectively making parse4cn1 compatible with Parse Server (regardless of whether you host it your self or use a third-party service). I expect to release the update next week.

Comment: Let us know if you want to write a guest post on this in the blog

Comment: back4app is not compatible with the parse4cn1 lib, and so with others too

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above, I'm in the process of releasing an update of parse4cn1 that will be Parse server compatible. I've also tested it against back4apps and it works fine. I'll be making a release this week though the changes are already in the develop branch of the github repo (if you need it fast)

Comment: @rockspetre: I've released the update that should answer the parse4cn1 part of your question: https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/releases/tag/parse4cn1-3.0 Have a look and let me know if you encounter any problems